# Running /usr/libexec/java_home gives invalid directory?

Tags: java, bash, directory

I ran this in my bash terminal as part of getting React Native app in Google Play Store (

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

It returned

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

I can go to "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins" but when I try to go to JavaAppletPlugin.plugin or JavaAppletPlugin it does not succeed. ls and ls -a don't show this place either..

What do?

Answer (score 0):

I used the ~ as (Users/) prefix but had to go even deeper back to / directory. From there I could find it